# How to use AfterJS getInitialProps in React functional components

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, prefetch

I can't get After.js (with Razzle) `getInitialProps` to work in functional components. Since I only use these kind of components (using hooks) I would need `getInitialProps` working with these components as well. Is there any way to do this?

I already tried suggestions from NextJS documentation using `Component.getInitialProps` before export but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const Component = () => { ... }

Component.getInitialProps = async ({ req, res, match, store, ...ctx }:any) => { 
    const setting = await fetch(apiUrl);
    return { setting };
};

export default Component;
```

In this code I would expect to see the setting prop on the server version.

Comment: Meanwhile I tried to create a HOC class component with getInitialProps to wrap the functional component in it but it doesn't seem to work